# Setting screen size on if statement inside function

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, media-queries, jsx

I want to have an if statement inside this function saying "if the screen size is x, then do this". Im not sure if there is an easy way to do this or if i have to do some funky stuff with css media queries and call that style

```
toggleSidebarMobile () {
    let state = this.state
    // if 
    state.sidebarOpened = !state.sidebarOpened
    this.setState(state);
    }
```

I want the function to only work on mobile devices.

Comment: this is a popular node module which might help you? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive

Answer (score 1):

You can set `window.innerWidth` to state in `componentDidMount()` and pass it down as a prop in your root component. After that create an event listener to listen to a **"resize"** event and update the state if the size changes.
For example:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    windowWidth:window.innerWidth
  })

  window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleScreenResize, true);
}

handleScreenResize = () => {
 this.setState({
    windowWidth:window.innerWidth
 })
}
```

Comment: You have the right idea. You should provide a small code snippet of what her `componentDidMount` function should look like! :)